# Simply modify "this.array[0]..." the typescript code

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

problem is,

```
  this.myList[0],
  this.myList[1],
  this.myList[2],
  this.myList[3], // mylist data is 0 ~ 18...
  this.myList[18]
```

I try is,

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.myList.length; i++) {
  this.myList.push(this.myList[i]);
}
```

But doesn't work. I write it like this,

```
this.myList.push(
  this.myList
);
```

Print it out as below.

```
 ...
   17: {name: undefined, value: Array(1), deptId: '100', deptName: 'asd', isChecked: false}
   18: {name: undefined, value: Array(1), deptId: '101', deptName: 'test', isChecked: false}
// I saved it repeatedly, but it was wrong.
   19: (20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, Array(20)]
// I saved it repeatedly, but it was wrong.
```

When the event starts, I want to load the data stored in myList one more time.
However, I don't know how to do it other than manual input.
What kind of ways are there? I want your help.

add +

I want to implement an infinite scroll.
Additional loading data must be output once again.
Like a clock ui.
When scrolling through the same data, I want to show it over and over again.
By the way, this.If myList.push (this.myList) is used, it will not be processed...
Is index an easy way to handle it? I don't know. Can I get help?

```
for ex) 
[ 1, 2, 3, ...1000 ] : myList 1st loading, 
[ 1000, 1, 2, 3, ...1000 ] : event > myList 1st + 2nd loading 
[ 1000, 1, 2, 3, ...1000 ] : event > myList 2nd + 3rd loading ...
```

Comment: I dont understand.. you are pushing `myList` data into the same array? also you are logging `this.checkboxList`. Can you explain what this is supposed to do?

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of explanation.

I want to implement an infinite scroll.

Additional loading data must be output once again. 

Like a clock ui.
for ex)
[ 1, 2, 3, ~1000 ] : myList 1st loading,
[ ~1000, 1, 2, 3, ~ 1000 ]  : event > myList 1st + 2nd loading        
[ 1000 1 2 3~ 1000 ]  : event > myList 2nd + 3rd loading   ...

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: It's a pity that I don't know how to use it. 
But why did it suddenly close?

Comment: I tried to find a similar solution, confused...

Comment: Not sure if i understand, but I think you want to concat your list to the same list? In that case, you can do this: ```this.myList.concat(this.myList)``` or ```this.myList = [...this.myList, ...this.myList]```

Comment: @J.Pinxten Thank you very much for your help, I'll test it out now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if i get it right, but your problem is, that this code

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.myList.length; i++) {
  this.myList.push(this.myList[i]);
}
```

modifies the array and with it it's length,

So each time you add an item the array gets one longer and so on.
This will eventually kill your heap for the array keeps expanding into infinity.

Maybe you want to loop until you reach the length of the inital array? If so you you should loop until

```
i<myList.length
```

However a simple concatenation by

```
this.myList.concat(this.myList)
```

or

```
this.myList = [...this.myList, ...this.myList]
```

would be the easiest and best solution.

Comment: thank you very much